# I cannot change the order of columns in a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I cannot change the order of columns in a SharePoint list and cannot figure out how to.  In the list settings, it is not shown as an option.

Can anyone please advise?
thanks.

Comment: To enable management of content types, go to the List Settings and click Advanced settings, it is the first option. Then the above post will show you how to reorder the columns.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on the dots near the view and click on **Modify this View**.

[image]

2. Then number the columns based on your requirement.

[image]